# PHP Hex to Integer

Tags: php

I'm integrating a PHP application with an API that uses permissions in the form of `0x00000008`, `0x20000000`, etc. where each of these represents a given permission.  Their API returned an integer.  In PHP, how do I interpret something like `0x20000000` into an integer so I can utilize bitwise operators?

Another dev told me he thought these numbers were hex annotation, but googling that in PHP I'm finding limited results.  **What kind of numbers are these and how can I take an `integer` set of permissions and using bitwise operators determine if the user can `0x00000008`**.

Comment: works out of the box.https://3v4l.org/g1ggf http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax

Comment: PHP supports `0x...` notation natively **for an integer variable**, but if you've got a string that you've received from an API, you'll need to run it through `hexdec()`

Comment: Can one of you post these as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the php documentation, much like what happens in the C language, this format is recognized in php as a native integer (in hexadecimal notation).

```
<?php
echo 0xDEADBEEF; // outputs 3735928559
```

**Demo** : https://3v4l.org/g1ggf

**Ref** : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax

Thus you could perform on them any bitwise operation since they are plain integers, with respect to the size of the registers on your server's processor (nowadays you are likely working on a 64-bit architecture, just saying in case it applies, you can confirm it with `phpinfo()` and through other means in doubt).

```
echo 0x00000001<<3; // 1*2*2*2, outputs 8
```

**Demo** : https://3v4l.org/AKv7H

**Ref** : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

As suggested by @iainn and @SaltyPotato in their respective answer and comment, since you are reading the data from an API you might have to deal with these values obtained as strings instead of native integers. To overcome this you would just have to go through the `hexdec` function to convert them before use.

**Ref** : http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Answer (score 2):

Since you are receiving it from an API php will interpret it as a string

`echo hexdec('0x00000008');`

returns the integer **8**

This should work.